# mounting the university drive with debian (CIFS), files do not synchronize

Tags: sync, mount

When I am at work and use my personal laptop, I connect to the university network by VPN and mount my network drive using following line in /etc/fstab (Debian testing)

```
//serverxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx /media/uni cifs defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/root/.xxxcredentials 0 0
```

The password and username is stored in the file /root/.xxxcredentials.

In order to mount the drive, I type:

```
sudo mount /media/uni
```

10 minutes ago, I changed something in one .py file within windows and switched to my laptop. I downloaded the changed file to my working folder and opened it using gedit, it was still the old file. So I deleted the file and repeated the process. Again, I had the old file back upon opening the downloaded file. Only renaming the file on the server and renaming it back on my laptop solved the issue.

Is there something I did not consider ? I cannot explain that behaviour with my (little) IT knowledge.

Comment: CIFS caching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920591/how-to-disable-caching-in-cifs-samba-on-client-side-in-linux

Comment: Tried to set `cache=none` in the fstab but it did not help.

Comment: Notification support might be related on the Debian side: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4071549/3981745 . From the Windows side, it's possible that "NoRemoteRecursiveEvents" (which affects CIFS) is set https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/885189 . If I'm reading the article correctly, a quick test may be to try the same operation at the "root" of the share - a file at /media/uni/ and not at /media/uni/somewhere_deeper/ - and see if the problem persists.